# Can Altair stepped line charts be configured to display the trailing stepped line like in Matplotlib step charts?

Tags: python, matplotlib, altair

Python code using Matplotlib produces a stepped line chart with the step trailing if the next y-axis value is None (or np.nan):

```
    x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    y = [1,2,3,None,5,6,7,8,None]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.step(x, y, where='post')
```

The equivalent Altair chart produces a similar stepped line chart but the trailing steps are missing if the next y-axis value in None:

```
    x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    y = [1,2,3,None,5,6,7,8,None]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
    chart = alt.Chart(
        df,
    ).mark_line(point=True, interpolate='step-after').encode(
        x='x',
        y=alt.Y('y:Q').scale(zero=False)
    ).interactive()
```

Results:
[Matplotlib Vs Altair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGvIt.png)

I haven't been able to find (and maybe there isn't a way) how to config the Altair chart to also show the trailing steps (like Matplotlib does). I hunted through the documentation and tried a bunch of settings (like using the `invalid=True` setting to include the None values but this works by making the value zero instead of None).

Preferably the solution won't involve adding fake rows to the Pandas Dataframe to simulate the trailing step because then the tooltip points become incorrect.